# Reshaping chunks of np array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape

I have a numpy array called "all_runs" that is comprised of hundreds of np arrays I appended together in a function. Here is an example of what it looks like when I append two arrays:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

I want to reshape this to the following:

```
0      1       2
0      1       2
0      1       2
0      1       2
0      1       2
0      1       2
0      1       2
0      1       2
```

I have tried this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(all_runs.reshape(3, 8))
```

but it is not giving the result I want:

```
0      0       0
0      1       1
1      1       2
2      2       2
0      0       0
0      1       1
1      1       2
2      2       2
```

Is there an efficient way to split the array and reshape it in the format shown above?

Comment: I think you mean `reshape(8, 3)`. Also, I don't think this can be reshaped to look like what you want. Is there a good reason to reshape instead of create?

Answer (score 1):

In one line:

```
a = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2])
print(np.vstack(np.hsplit(a.reshape(6,4).transpose(),2)))
```

Output:

```
[[0 1 2]
 [0 1 2]
 [0 1 2]
 [0 1 2]
 [0 1 2]
 [0 1 2]
 [0 1 2]
 [0 1 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be better off creating your array differently, so you don't have to reshape your array. It might be simpler to format your array into its shape when creating it rather than appending then reshaping.

Regardless, you have to consider order of the axes when reshaping. It ends up being somewhat convoluted, but you could try this:

```
arr = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2])
np.vstack(arr.reshape([2, -1]).reshape(2, 3, -1).transpose([0, 2, 1]))
```

Output:

```
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort your array and then reshape it as.

```
import numpy as np
test = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]
test = np.asarray(test)
np.sort().reshape(3,8)
```

Output

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
   [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]])
```